# Confusion regarding bode plot?

Tags: bode-plot, cutoff-frequency

I am trying to understand bode plot and i came across attached snap especially black solid  line in magnitude plot, i captured this snap from wikipedia. Here i am confused,what is cutt off frequency? Since cutt off frequecny is the one where gain is  3db less than gain of  pass band. I think here cutt off frequecny is 100 Hz but if it is cutt off then why is its gain value  exactly equal to pass band gain?It should be  3db less

[image]

Comment: The label says that the black line is an approximation. The red point are -3 dB at 100 Hz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The black solid lines are asymptotes. These are easy to draw, to help you to approximate the correct curve, which as you say is 3dB<sup>1</sup> down at the cutoff frequency for a single pole curve. Frequently, engineers will just work with the asymptotes, knowing that the correct curve is not far away.

I find that the phase approximation shown here is often not sufficiently accurate when designing high order PLL loop filters. I prefer to approximate it using the ratio of the frequency to the cutoff frequency, as 60/ratio degrees error from the constant phase lines, except for the cutoff frequency itself

| frequency ratio | degrees |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 |
| 2 | 30 |
| 4 | 15 |
| 8 | 7.5 |
| etc |  |

This is itself an approximation, but a lot better than that shown above, and very useful for estimating how far you need to be from the cutoff frequency of a high order filter to have it giving you only (say) 20 degrees phase shift to destabilise your loop.

(1) Even that's an approximation, they are 3.01dB<sup>2</sup> down. Engineering is about finding the right level of approximation.

(2) 3.0103 to 5 figures. You can add more, but that would be silly.

Comment: you mean"asymptotes"are just approximation??

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/asymptote.html

Comment: @engr 'just' is a four letter word. Asymptotes are a very useful mathematical concept with widespread application. Here, they make a difficult-to-calculate-in-your-head curve very easy to approximate, especially if all you have is the back of an envelope.